# SSH over Ethernet directly to PC causes: client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset

Tags: ssh, pi-5

I have my pi 5 (fresh install) (also tested pi 4, same issue) connected via ethernet cable to my PC (windows 11). SSH into the pi 5, after about 2 minutes, causes:

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
```

I can't ssh back into the pi unless I replug the ethernet cable. I have tested this now from two host PCs.

Connecting the pi to my router does not cause the error.

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Pi OS:

Bookworm (64 BIT 2023-12-05)

Pi version:

Pi5

Edit2: Tested now on two PCs, issue persists

Comment: *"What could be the cause of this behaviour?"* mmm... i'll need to think about that.